# Why a returned callback does not have access to its outer context like a closure?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

Situation 1. Curried function:

```
const foo = a => b => a + b
const bar = foo('a')
bar('b') // prints 'ab'
```

Situation 2. Callback:

```
const foo = a => a + b
const wrap = (callback, b) => callback
const wrapped = wrap(foo, 'b')
wrapped('a') // b is undefined
```

I have already tried several changes on Situation 2, but the result is always the same: error because `b` is undefined. I do not understand why, thought, since - from my point of view - it's basically currying by other ways. But I'm clearly wrong. Situation 1 works and Situation 2 does not.
I would like to know why and if there's any situation in which Situation 2 could compile.

Comment: The variables come from where the function appears, not where it’s referenced. At `const foo = a => a + b`, the scope for the arrow function is the scope that contains `foo` (i.e. `foo`, `wrap`, and `wrapped`) and its own scope, which contains only `a`.

Comment: `b` is not undefined here `const foo = a => a + b`

Comment: @Ryan, you mean that the scope is binded to `foo` when I create it? So, no matter what I do, if `foo` has been written in a global context I can call it anywhere, I will only read it's own scope and the global one?
@TigerTV.ru, sorry, I don't understand. I tried the code before pasting it here and yes, `b` is undefined on Situation 2.

Comment: A closure (in JS) encloses the variables from the context where the function has been defined, not where it is used/passed to.

Answer (score 0):

In situation 2. you defined a function const `foo = a => a + b`, that only accepts one argument (`a`), so `b` is not passed into the function.

And `b` is also not defined in the global scope, so it can`t be other than undefined.

Try playing around with `foo = a => b => a + b` or `foo = (a, b) => a + b`